# Как вычислить более выгодное направление для поворота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, логика

Мне нужно вращать спрайт так, чтобы angle1 (в коде) был равен angle2 (там же), а вращать спрайт надо с определённым шагом например по 2 градуса за кадр ещё при if angle > 360: angle-=360 вращается автоматически и всё начинается с нуля, может я тупой. Код есть только:

```
def point_towards_with_steps(self, step_angle, x, y=None):
    try:
        x, y = x.x, x.y #если указан объект
    except AttributeError:
        x, y = x, y #если указана точка
    angle2=_math.degrees(_math.atan2(y-self.y, x-self.x))#угол к которому надо привести спрайт
    angle1=self.angle #угол спрайта
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ничего непонятно. А так то что 360 градусов, что -360, что 0 - это один и тот же угол по сути.

Comment: А чего там вычислять-то? Вычесть из требуемого угла текущий. Если полученная разница по модулю меньше 180 то крутить в ту же сторону (с тем же знаком), иначе в противоположную. Например, текущий 100, требуемый 90. Разница равна -10, по модулю 10<180 - значит крутим с тем же знаком (в данном случае в минус). Текущий 10, требуемый 270, разница 260, по модулю 260>180, крутим с противоположным знаком (опять в минус, через 0).